# Do SPF Records For Primary Domain apply to subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, email-server, spf

I have a quick question regarding SPF records: Do they need to be present for all subdomains?

Lets say that I have a TXT record with SPF info for domain.com

Let's also say that I have a seperate email domain for subdomain.domain.com

Will the SPF policy/info for domain.com also apply to the subdomain? Or do I need to add a separate TXT record for that too?

Comment: Note that you can have wildcard SPFs for subdomains: search wildcards below.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to have separate SPF records for each subdomain you wish to send mail from.

The following was originally posted on openspf.org, which used to be a great resource for this kind of thing.

Latest link http://www.open-spf.org/FAQ/The_demon_question/

> The Demon Question: What about subdomains?
>
> If I get mail from
> pielovers.demon.co.uk, and there's no SPF data for pielovers, should I
> go back one level and test SPF for demon.co.uk? No. Each subdomain at
> Demon is a different customer, and each customer might have their own
> policy. It wouldn't make sense for Demon's policy to apply to all its
> customers by default; if Demon wants to do that, it can set up SPF
> records for each subdomain.
>
> So the advice to SPF publishers is this: you should add an SPF record
> for each subdomain or hostname that has an A or MX record.
>
> Sites with wildcard A or MX records should also have a wildcard SPF
> record, of the form: * IN TXT "v=spf1 -all"

This makes sense - a subdomain may very well be in a different geographical location and have a very different SPF definition.

The 'include:' directive for SPF may be used to provide all subdomains with the same entries.  For example, on the SPF record for subdomain mailfrom.example.com enter 'include:example.com'. In this fashion whenever you update the definition for example.com your subdomains will automatically pick up the updated values.

Comment: link to openspf doesn't work for me atm, but luckily the internet archive has us covered: https://web.archive.org/web/20190129091342/http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/The_demon_question

Comment: Current link to The Demon Question: http://www.open-spf.org/action_browse_diff_1_id_FAQ/The_demon_question/

Comment: http://www.open-spf.org/FAQ/The_demon_question/

Answer (score 31):

In addition to the other answers, **if a subdomain is created as a CNAME record, the SPF record is the one for the domain it points to**, e.g. `sub.domain.com` is a CNAME of `otherdomain.com`, the SPF a mailserver will get when it looks up `mail@sub.domain.com` is in the DNS record for `otherdomain.com`.

This is the same in practice if the CNAME record says sub.domain.com => othersub.domain.com, so your TXT record would need to be othersub, not sub. This is in contrast to DKIM, which needs a separate TXT record for the public key, even if your subdomain is a CNAME.

Answer (score 6):

But note, as it says in the FAQ referenced in the accepted answer, that you can have wildcard SPFs for a domain for wildcard A or MX records. I have wildcard MX domains, and this works for me:

```
*.mydomain.org. 3600 IN  TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:IPADDR -all"
```

with IPADDR replaced with your IP address/range.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can short-circuit them with the `include:maindomain.invalid` directive.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'm curious...  How would that directive work?

Answer (score 2):

```
*.mydomain.org. 3600 IN  TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:IPADDR -all"
```

as written above does not work if the spammer uses a subdomain that is already in dDNS. For example www.domain.com A A records foresides the wildcard in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the include statement only includes A-records from the specified domain and not subdomains either. So it does not pick up A-records from subdomains and therefore it only works when all subdomains are on the same server or send from the same server.

Comment: I don't think this answer pertains to the question (which concerns SPF records, i.e. `TXT`) at all?

Comment: I think the warning in this answer was about the case where 1) the top-level domain specified an SPF record including 'a' 2) the sub-domain included the top-level domain SPF, expecting to pick up the exact same set of IP addresses, but actually picked up the sub-domain A record.

Comment: @AdamS, the opposite actually occurs. Suppose: • `example.com A` returns `192.168.0.10`; • `example.com TXT` returns `v=spf1 a -all`; • `sub.example.com A` returns `192.168.0.20`; and • `sub.example.com TXT` returns `v=spf1 include:example.com -all`. Then mail for `sub.example.com` is permitted to be sent from `192.168.0.10` alone.